# Reset my running total on specfic column value in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Here I have column `InOutType`:

```
1 means in stock 
2 means out stock 
3 means reset count and start from given quantity.
```

I want to get running total as below:

```
RowNum ProductName InOutType  quantity runningTotal 

   1     Apple          1        10         10
   2     Orange         1        20         20
   3     Apple          2        5          5
   4     Apple          1        2          7
   5     Orange         2        8          12
   6     Orange         3        5          5
   7     Apple          3        2          2
   8     Orange         1        20         25
   9     Apple          1        10         12 
   10    Apple          2        2          10
   11    Orange         2        8          17
```

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT productName,InOutType,quantity, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN InOutType = 1 THEN quantity WHEN InOutType = 2 THEN -quantity ELSE quantity END) over (partition by uniqueKeyProduct order by RowNum) AS runningTotal 
FROM InventoryTable
```

Comment: SELECT productName,InOutType,quantity, SUM(CASE WHEN InOutType = 1 THEN quantity WHEN InOutType = 2 THEN -quantity ELSE quantity END) over (partition by uniqueKeyProduct order by RowNum) AS runningTotal 
FROM InventoryTable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With window functions `MAX()` and `SUM()`:

```
select RowNum, ProductName, InOutType, quantity,
  sum(case when InOutType = 2 then -1 else 1 end * quantity)
  over (partition by ProductName, start order by RowNum) runningTotal 
from (
  select *,    
    max(case when InoutType = 3 then RowNum end) over (partition by ProductName order by RowNum) start
  from tablename
)  
order by RowNum
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aENmSv9RPJmyc9pJR9VZAj/1).
Results:

```
| RowNum | ProductName | InOutType | quantity | runningTotal |
| ------ | ----------- | --------- | -------- | ------------ |
| 1      | Apple       | 1         | 10       | 10           |
| 2      | Orange      | 1         | 20       | 20           |
| 3      | Apple       | 2         | 5        | 5            |
| 4      | Apple       | 1         | 2        | 7            |
| 5      | Orange      | 2         | 8        | 12           |
| 6      | Orange      | 3         | 5        | 5            |
| 7      | Apple       | 3         | 2        | 2            |
| 8      | Orange      | 1         | 20       | 25           |
| 9      | Apple       | 1         | 10       | 12           |
| 10     | Apple       | 2         | 2        | 10           |
| 11     | Orange      | 2         | 8        | 17           |
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: On 1500 record it is taking 623ms to 650ms

Comment: Both solution is working but this is taking less time then Shawn solution

Comment: @forpus can we get same result if I dont have RowNum column but i have column with unique key of type string? I had used ROW_NUMBER () to get RowNum column but room database doesn't support this function.

Comment: @Shambhusharan without a column like `RowNum` which defines the order on which the running total can be calculated you can't do it. Can that string column that yu have define the order of the rows? Also if ROOM does not support ROW_NUMBER() I assume it does not support also any window function. If this is the case then probably you shouldn't use ROOM because it leaves out features of SQLite that were added 2 years ago.

Comment: @forpus, how can I get same result without using windows function . android sqlite support v3.19. showing error near over (partition ...

Comment: @Shambhusharan you could use Shawn's code if you change ROW_NUMBER() with a correlated subquery: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aENmSv9RPJmyc9pJR9VZAj/2, but this would not be as fast as the code with window functions.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Can we simplified above query if I dont need ROW_NUMBER() ? I have one column with unique id (type text).

Comment: @Shambhusharan a unique column is not enough. You need a column denoting the order for each ProductName to get the running total. This is why ROW_NUMBER() or the correlated subquery is used.

Comment: I have already created a view in sorted order by using order by on some column. And I have to query on that view.

Comment: @Shambhusharan I only know the sample data in your question. If your actual data is different you can post a new question with that data. In any case you still need either ROW_NUMBER or similar code without window functions to get a row number for each ProductName, because without it you can't  produce a running total.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat ugly way using window functions and a recursive CTE:

```sql
WITH grouped AS
 (SELECT RowNum, ProductName, InOutType, Quantity,
         row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductName ORDER BY RowNum) AS grn
 FROM stock),
summed AS
 (SELECT RowNum, ProductName, InOutType, Quantity, Quantity AS RunningTotal, grn
  FROM grouped WHERE grn = 1
 UNION ALL
  SELECT s.RowNum, s.ProductName, s.InOutType, s.Quantity,
         CASE s.InOutType
              WHEN 1 THEN sp.RunningTotal + s.Quantity
              WHEN 2 THEN sp.RunningTotal - s.Quantity
              WHEN 3 THEN s.Quantity
          END,
          s.grn
  FROM grouped AS s
  JOIN summed AS sp ON s.ProductName = sp.ProductName
                   AND s.grn = sp.grn + 1) 
SELECT RowNum, ProductName, InOutType, Quantity, RunningTotal
FROM summed
ORDER BY RowNum;
```

This produces

```
RowNum      ProductName  InOutType   Quantity    RunningTotal
----------  -----------  ----------  ----------  ------------
1           Apple        1           10          10          
2           Orange       1           20          20          
3           Apple        2           5           5           
4           Apple        1           2           7           
5           Orange       2           8           12          
6           Orange       3           5           5           
7           Apple        3           2           2           
8           Orange       1           20          25          
9           Apple        1           10          12          
10          Apple        2           2           10          
11          Orange       2           8           17
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn it giving required result . Is Any optimized way to do same?

Comment: @Shambhusharan An index on `(ProductName,RowNum)` would be very useful.

Comment: On 1500 record it is taking 880ms to 920ms

Comment: how can I get same result without using windows function . android sqlite support v3.19. showing error near over (partition ...